# Consider X flags for closing a question as a vote to close it

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flagging

As it is now, flags for closing a question are not considered as votes to close it.

Would not make sense to consider X flags for closing a question as a vote to close it? X could be a value sufficient high to avoid that two users flagging a question are considered a vote to close it, but it should not be a too high number.
In this way, moderators don't need to check the number of flags for closing a question, and with the right number of users flagging a question, they could not need to do anything at all.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a solution for a non-existent problem. We have enough high rep users that can vote to close; we have active moderators; we have an active chat. As the site grows, the time-to-close will continue to shrink.

On the other hand, allowing flaggers to close is problematic because anyone over 15 rep can flag and there isn't any rep loss for poor flagging skills. There is a reason voting to close happens at 3000 rep.

In the meantime, people can now downvote for free. I think flag+downvote is effective enough for people who cannot cast a legitimate close vote.

Comment: Down-voting a question is different from voting for closing a question; not all the questions that are closed are down-voted. If all the closed questions would be also down-voted, then I would think something is wrong.

Comment: Agreed. I guess my point was just to point out that downvoting is still an option.

Comment: It is an option, but it doesn't have the same effect; the only way to close a question is voting to close it. If X flags for closing it would count as a vote to close it, then also flagging it would be an option to close it.